# Broken IMG upon Compilation HTML

Tags: html, xhtml

All images appears to be a Broken images icon in my HTML.

Im pretty sure that i was using the right file extension and file name

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
   <img src = 'PUPLogo.PNG'/> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have an online fiddle or plunker ? or a screen shot to provide details ? Depending on your O/S, it could be a case-sensitivity issue, or perhaps you're missing the correct file path. See this simple online sample - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_test

Comment: Where do you test that? Note that many mobile devices don't display PNG...

Comment: @basZero Chrome, I am using Notepad++.

Comment: Have you tried changing to using double quotes? Also, I would check that the file path is correct. The way you have that path written means that the PNG should be in the same directory